# How do you display a comment as text with html?

Tags: html

I know you can display html tags inside `<code>` blocks to display html as text by replacing < with `&lt;` and > with `&gt;`. How do you escape the comment tag?

Comment: Use the pre tag or use &lt;!--

Comment: You seem to have answered this yourself! `<code>&lt;!-- Comment --&gt;</code>`

Comment: `&lt;!-- this is comment --&gt;` ??

Comment: Thanks! I'm kicking myself for not realizing. Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 0):

```
&lt;!-- comments --&gt;
```

This should work